# Ear installation fails on Websphere 8.5

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I am trying to install an .ear which was running in WebSphere Platform 7.0.0.17 version on WebSphere Platform 8.5.5.2 via admin. So basically its an upgrade process to higher version of websphere
I expected it to install but not deploy because of the version difference.

SystemErr.log shows this.

************* End Display Current Environment *************
[1/7/15 17:57:32:077 GMT+05:30] 000000a8 SystemErr     R java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
[1/7/15 17:57:32:077 GMT+05:30] 000000a8 SystemErr     R    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1256)
[1/7/15 17:57:32:077 GMT+05:30] 000000a8 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.updateModuleNameUniqueness(ConfigureTask.java:3331)
[1/7/15 17:57:32:078 GMT+05:30] 000000a8 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.performTask(ConfigureTask.java:373)
[1/7/15 17:57:32:078 GMT+05:30] 000000a8 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:315)
[1/7/15 17:57:32:078 GMT+05:30] 000000a8 SystemErr     R    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:853)

SystemOut.log

`[1/7/15 17:57:01:255 GMT+05:30] 0000008f FileRepositor A   ADMR0010I: Document cells/MyApp01Cell/nodes/MyAppNode01/serverindex.xml is modified.
[1/7/15 17:57:23:416 GMT+05:30] 000000a8 InstallSchedu I   ADMA5016I: Installation of applet started.
[1/7/15 17:57:31:624 GMT+05:30] 000000a8 WSDeployTask  A   WSWS0041I: Web services deploy task completed successfully.
[1/7/15 17:57:32:035 GMT+05:30] 000000a8 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /usr/local/IBM/WebSphere8.5.5.2/AppServer/profiles/MyApp/logs/ffdc/server1_83d7abd6_15.01.07_17.57.31.9457226982159431677167.txt com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.performTask 471
[1/7/15 17:57:32:076 GMT+05:30] 000000a8 FfdcProvider  W com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: FFDC Incident emitted on /usr/local/IBM/WebSphere8.5.5.2/AppServer/profiles/MyApp/logs/ffdc/server1_83d7abd6_15.01.07_17.57.32.0367510307927570797580.txt com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.performTask 484
[1/7/15 17:57:32:110 GMT+05:30] 000000a8 InstallSchedu I   ADMA5014E: The installation of application applet failed.`

FFDC Incident is also generated but I am unable to make much of it.

Did someone hit this? Can you give me some pointers?

Part of the FFDC incident log ...

```
[1/7/15 17:57:31:956 GMT+05:30]     FFDC Exception:java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.performTask ProbeId:471 Reporter:java.lang.Class@9b9b49c0
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1256)
at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.updateModuleNameUniqueness(ConfigureTask.java:3331)
at com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask.performTask(ConfigureTask.java:373)
at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:315)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:853)

CapturedDataElements begin
arg0 BEGIN:com.ibm.ws.management.application.task.ConfigureTask@670e3ba3
com.ibm.websphere.management.application.task.AbstractTask::defaultBundleName:com.ibm.ws.management.resources.AppDeploymentMessages
com.ibm.websphere.management.application.task.AbstractTask::locale BEGIN:java.util.Locale@6a518946
en_US
END:java.util.Locale@6a518946

com.ibm.websphere.management.application.task.AbstractTask::appTaskName:InstallApplication
com.ibm.websphere.management.application.task.AbstractTask::bundle:null
com.ibm.websphere.management.application.task.AbstractTask::scheduler BEGIN:com.ibm.ws.management.application.InstallSchedulerImpl@6fdc620f
com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl::tc BEGIN:com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent@b6ad5ebc
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivLevel:10
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivName:com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivDebugEnabled:false
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivEventEnabled:false
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivEntryEnabled:false
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivDetailEnabled:false
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivConfigEnabled:false
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivInfoEnabled:true
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivServiceEnabled:true
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivWarningEnabled:true
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivErrorEnabled:true
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceElement::ivFatalEnabled:true
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::defaultMessageFile:com.ibm.ejs.resources.seriousMessages
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::EXTENSION_NAME_DPID:DiagnosticProvider
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivDumpEnabled:false
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivResourceBundleName:com.ibm.ws.management.resources.AppDeploymentMessages
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivLogger:null
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::ivDiagnosticProviderID:null
com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent::anyTracingEnabled:null
END:com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent@b6ad5ebc
```

Application.xml

```
<application>
    <display-name>Product applet</display-name>
    <module>    
        <web>
            <web-uri>my_war</web-uri>
            <context-root>applet</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
</application>
```

Comment: Anything in the SystemOut.log?

Comment: @Gas I updated the description with the messages in SystemOut.log

Comment: It doesn't provide much details. So you could paste first stacktrace from both ffdc `/usr/local/IBM/WebSphere8.5.5.2/AppServer/profiles/OSS82/logs/ffdc/server1_83d7abd6_15.01.07_17.57.31.9457226982159431677167.txt` and `/usr/local/IBM/WebSphere8.5.5.2/AppServer/profiles/OSS82/logs/ffdc/server1_83d7abd6_15.01.07_17.57.32.0367510307927570797580.txt` maybe there will be something there. Otherwise you will have to open PMR in IBM Support.

Comment: Hmm, the `ConfigureTask.updateModuleNameUniqueness` suggests that there maybe something wrong with the module names. Can you add `application.xml` and also check if you don't have similar modules already installed in different apps on the server.

Comment: In any case, this is a very poor error message, so it would be good to open a PMR with IBM to improve that.

Comment: @Gas Thanks. I added the application.xml content.

Comment: Looks like `web-uri` might be wrong. Please try to add `.war` etension, like this `<web-uri>seq_war.war</web-uri>`. This may help.

Comment: By adding `.war` the deployment goes through fine, but I get fileNotFound and URL related exceptions specific to my application. Can I find some documentation from IBM which says we have to add `.war` and other info.

Comment: Fixing some of the application issues, I was able to bring my application without any issues. I now have to find some documentation for the `.war` workaround/fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `application.xml` associated modules should contain module name with the extension (eg. .war, .jar, .rar). See the description in the application.xml [schema file](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd):

> The web-uri element specifies the URI of a web application file,
>   relative to the top level of the application package.

So in your case you should have:

```
<web-uri>my_war.war</web-uri>
```

if the file contained in the `.ear` is called `my_war.war`

Comment: The file contained in the `.ear` is called `my_war` and not `my_war.war`. So, I need to change it to `my_war.war` in `application.xml` and the file name in `.ear`.

Answer (score 0):

I used the adding `.war` workaround suggested by @Gas and my application comes up. However, I still have to find the documentation from IBM to confirm.

Thanks.